# I get the error: no matching constructor for initialization of std::pair when trying to emplace objects in map

Tags: c++, c++17

I've tried emplacing my custom type Exercise as key and Open_polyline from Stroustrup's Graph_lib into a map without any luck. Inserting the objects doesn't help me.

Do I have to have a default constructor for key and value of each pair in a map?

The error I get is as follows:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include\xmemory(671,76): error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::pair<const Exercise, Graph_lib::Open_polyline>' 
::new (const_cast<void*>(static_cast<const volatile void*>(_Ptr))) _Objty(_STD forward<_Types>(_Args)...);
```

The function where the problem arises:

`graphs` is a member of type `map<Exercise, Open_polyline>`.

```
void WorkoutManager::updateGraphs(const bool state) {

    if (state) {
        
        for (auto w : loadedWorkouts) {
            // Date indicates location on x axis.
            // Each workout type gets its own graph.
            // Each weight of workout indicates location on y axis.
            
            int x_coord = stoi(date::format("%d", w.getDate().day()));
            const set<ExerciseSet> exs = w.getResults();
            
            int i {0}; // For Color picking.
            for (ExerciseSet es : exs) {
                // If exercise is found in map, point is added to existing graph.
                if (graphs.find(es.type) != graphs.end()) {
                    graphs.find(es.type)->second.add(Point{x_coord, es.weight});
                }
                
                else {
                    // Exercise not found: creates new graph.
                    Open_polyline opl;
                    opl.set_style(Line_style::solid);
                    opl.set_color(Color(i));
                    opl.add(Point{x_coord, es.weight}); // Adds new point to graph.

                    graphs.emplace(es.type, opl); // <-- ERROR HERE!
                }

                ++i;
            }
        }

        for (auto it = graphs.begin(); it != graphs.end(); ++it) {
            attach(it->second);
        }
    }
    else {
        // graphs.empty(); // <-- This also gives error.
    }
}
```

The `Shape` class which `Open_polyline` inherits from in `Graph.h`.
Classes are here only shown with their constructors.

```
class Shape
{ // deals with color and style, and holds sequence of lines
protected:
    Shape()
    {}

    Shape(initializer_list<Point> lst)
    {
        for (Point p : lst)
            add(p);
    } // add() the Points to this Shape
    
    ...
};

struct Open_polyline : Shape
{ // open sequence of lines
    using Shape::Shape;
    
    ...
};
```

The `Exercise` enum and the `ExerciseSet` class:

```
#pragma once

#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "date.h" // Substitute for C++20 <chrono> which was not released yet.

using namespace std;

// Enumeration for exercises.
enum Exercise {
    ArnoldPress,
    BenchPress,
    BenchPressIncline,
    BenchPressDecline,
    BicepsCurl,
    CableFlies,
    Deadlift,
    EZBarCurl,
    HammerCurl,
    LatPullDown,
    LatRaise,
    LegCurl,
    LegExt,
    LegPress,
    Pulley,
    ShoulderPress,
    Squat,
    StandingRow,
    TriBenchExt,
    TriPullDownBar,
    TriPullDownRope
};

// Class to give a exercise a corresponding weight.
struct ExerciseSet {
    Exercise type;
    int weight;

    ExerciseSet(Exercise type, int weight) : type{type}, weight{weight} {}

    // Required to add this class to a set.
    bool operator<(const ExerciseSet& r) const;
    bool operator==(const ExerciseSet& r) const;
};
```

Comment: what is `Exercise`? Please try to create a [mcve]

Comment: Does `open_Polyline` have a copy or move constructor?

Comment: My educated guess would be, `Open_polyline` (or one of its base classes) contains a non-copyable data member, and therefore is not itself copyable.

Comment: `Open_polyline` does not have a copy or move constructor, but I tried implementing a specialised class which added copy constructor, but it didn't solve the problem. Can the problem lie in the Exercise enum?

Comment: No, the problem is not with `Exercise` enum. The pieces of the code you've shown [compile](https://godbolt.org/z/8Kj44j). To the extent there is a problem, it lies in the code not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments to this post, the problem lied in the lack of copy contructor for the `Open_polyline` class. My own solution to this problem was to use pointers to `Open_polyline` objects, to emplace them inside the `map`.